Highlight Days in PrimeReact Calendar Based on Range Selection with Hover
I am working on a React TypeScript application using PrimeReact (version 10.8.3), specifically the Calendar component with Range selection mode. I created a separate component for the Calendar and customized it to implement a feature where it highlights all days between the first selected date and the hovered date, even across different years, for example:
I have selected the first date as 1 December 2023 then if a user hovers over any date after that, even dates in different years (say 2024) it should highlight all the days from 2 December to the hovered day.
Something like this, the only thing different in my case it shows one month at a time:
Example Image
Here is my react tsx code:
// calendar-component.tsx
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Calendar } from "primereact/calendar";
import "./calendar-component.scss";
import moment from "moment";
import { getDatesBetween, getMonthsYears } from "../../../utils/sharedUtils";

interface ICalendarProps {
  handleDateFilter: (dates: Date[]) => void;
  maxDate?: Date;
  dateFormat?: string;
}

function CalendarComponent({
  handleDateFilter,
  maxDate,
  dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
}: ICalendarProps) {
  const [dates, setDates] = useState([new Date(), new Date()]);
  const calendarRef = useRef<any>(null);
  const calendarInputRef = useRef<any>(null);
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [viewDate, setViewDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [rangeDates, setRangeDates] = useState<any[]>([]);
  // const [dayCells, setDayCells] = useState<Element[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (dates?.[0] && dates?.[1]) {
      handleDateFilter(dates);
    }
    setDynamicWidth();
  }, [dates]);

  const handleCalendarOpen = () => {
    calendarRef.current?.hide();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const tableScroller = document.querySelector(".p-datatable-wrapper");
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleCalendarOpen);
    tableScroller?.addEventListener("scroll", handleCalendarOpen);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleCalendarOpen);
      tableScroller?.removeEventListener("scroll", handleCalendarOpen);
    };
  }, []);

  const handleMouseOver = (e: any) => {
    const { month, year } = getMonthsYears(new Date(viewDate));
    const day = Number(e.target.textContent);
    const hoveredDate = new Date(year, month, day);
    if (
      (dates[0] && hoveredDate?.getTime() < dates[0]?.getTime()) ||
      (dates[1] && hoveredDate?.getTime() > dates[1]?.getTime())
    ) {
      return;
    }
    setRangeDates((prevList) => [
      ...getDatesBetween(new Date(dates[0]), hoveredDate)?.map((val) =>
        val.toString()
      ),
    ]);
  };

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   if (dayCells.length) {
  //
  //     dayCells.forEach((cell) => {
  //       cell.addEventListener("mouseover", handleMouseOver);
  //       return () => {
  //         cell.removeEventListener("mouseover", handleMouseOver);
  //       };
  //     });
  //   }
  //   // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  // }, [dayCells]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (viewDate && isOpen) {
      const dayCellsTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        const dayCells = document.querySelectorAll(".custom-day-label");
        dayCells.forEach((cell) => {
          const isDisabled = cell.getAttribute("data-p-disabled");
          if (isDisabled === "false") {
            cell.addEventListener("mouseover", handleMouseOver);
            return () => {
              cell.removeEventListener("mouseover", handleMouseOver);
            };
          }
        });
      }, 0);
      return () => {
        clearTimeout(dayCellsTimeout);
        const dayCells = document.querySelectorAll(".custom-day-label");
        dayCells.forEach((cell) => {
          cell.removeEventListener("mouseover", handleMouseOver);
        });
      };
    }
  }, [viewDate, isOpen, dates, rangeDates]); //  flickering causing due to rangeDates dependency but removing it stops it from listening to the mouseover as reference to the current dayCells changes

  useEffect(() => {
    if (dates[0] && rangeDates?.length > 0) {
      const { month, year } = getMonthsYears(new Date(viewDate));
      const highlightTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        const dayCells = document.querySelectorAll(".custom-day-label");
        dayCells.forEach((cell: any, cellIndex: number) => {
          const cellDate = new Date(year, month, cell.textContent);
          const isHiglighted = cell.getAttribute("data-p-highlight");
          const isDisabled = cell.getAttribute("data-p-disabled");
          if (
            dates[0].toString() !== cellDate.toString() &&
            (!dates[1] || dates[1].toString() !== cellDate.toString()) &&
            isHiglighted === "false" &&
            isDisabled === "false"
          ) {
            if (rangeDates.includes(cellDate.toString())) {
              cell.style.backgroundColor = "#e3e9f7";
            } else {
              cell.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            }
          }
        });
      }, 0);
      return () => {
        clearTimeout(highlightTimeout);
      };
    }
  }, [dates, rangeDates, viewDate]);

  const setDynamicWidth = () => {
    const hiddenSpan = document.createElement("span");
    hiddenSpan.className = "hiddenSpan";
    hiddenSpan.textContent = getDisplayValue().toString();
    hiddenSpan.style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.body.appendChild(hiddenSpan);
    if (hiddenSpan && calendarInputRef.current) {
      hiddenSpan.textContent = getDisplayValue().toString();
      calendarInputRef.current.style.width =
        hiddenSpan.getClientRects()[0].width + "px";
      document.body.removeChild(hiddenSpan);
    }
  };

  const getDisplayValue = () => {
    return dates[0] && dates[1] && dates[0].getTime() === dates[1].getTime()
      ? moment(dates[0]).format("DD MMM YYYY")
      : `${dates[0] ? moment(dates[0]).format("DD MMM YYYY") : ""} - ${
          dates[1] ? moment(dates[1]).format("DD MMM YYYY") : ""
        }`;
  };

  return (
    <div className="calendar-wrapper">
      <Calendar
        panelClassName="date-filter-panel"
        value={dates}
        onChange={(e: any) => setDates(e.value)}
        selectionMode="range"
        readOnlyInput
        maxDate={maxDate || new Date()}
        showIcon
        iconPos="left"
        dateFormat={dateFormat}
        ref={calendarRef}
        inputRef={calendarInputRef}
        viewDate={viewDate}
        onShow={() => setIsOpen(true)}
        onHide={() => {
          setIsOpen(false);
          setRangeDates([]);
        }}
        onViewDateChange={(e) => {
          setViewDate(e.value);
        }}
        pt={{
          dayLabel: {
            className: "custom-day-label",
          },
        }}
      />
      <div
        className="display-value"
        style={{ width: calendarInputRef?.current?.style?.width + "px" }}
      >
        {getDisplayValue()}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CalendarComponent;

// sharedUtils.ts:
export const getDatesBetween = (startDate: Date, endDate: Date) => {
  const dates: any[] = [];
  const currentDate = new Date(startDate);

  // Ensure that startDate is before endDate
  if (startDate > endDate) return dates;

  while (currentDate <= endDate) {
    dates.push(new Date(currentDate));
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1); // Increment the date
  }
  return dates;
};

export const getMonthsYears = (date: Date) => {
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  const month = date.getMonth();
  return { year, month };
};

// calendar-component.scss
@import "../../../styles/variable.scss";

.calendar-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: fit-content;
  .p-calendar {
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #d0d5dd;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px #1018280d;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: fit-content;
    background: white;
    .p-button {
      background-color: $whiteColor !important;
      color: $blackColor;
      border: none !important;
      border-top-left-radius: 4px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    }
    .p-inputtext {
      border: none !important;
      border-top-right-radius: 4px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 600;
      padding-left: 0;
      z-index: 9;
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
  .display-value {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    left: 38px;
    height: 40px;
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    border-top: 1px solid #d0d5dd;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  }
  .p-calendar:not(.p-calendar-disabled).p-focus > .p-inputtext {
    box-shadow: none !important;
  }
}

.date-filter-panel {
  margin-left: -38px;
  margin-top: 1.5px;
  width: 310px !important;
  .p-datepicker-group {
    .p-datepicker-header {
      .p-datepicker-title {
        font-size: 15px;
        .p-datepicker-month {
          font-family: "Inter-Medium";
          padding-right: 6px;
          letter-spacing: 0.5px;
          &:enabled:hover {
            color: #4b5563;
          }
        }
        .p-datepicker-year {
          padding-left: 0;
          font-family: "Inter-Medium";
          letter-spacing: 0.5px;
          &:enabled:hover {
            color: #4b5563;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    .p-datepicker-calendar-container {
      .p-datepicker-calendar {
        font-size: 13px;
        thead {
          tr {
            font-weight: 500;
            color: #7e818c;
          }
        }
        tbody {
          tr {
            td {
              font-family: "Inter-Medium";
              font-weight: 500;
              padding: 7px;
              span {
                width: 28px;
                height: 28px;
              }
              span.p-highlight {
                background-color: $primaryColor;
                color: $whiteColor;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

.date-filter-panel
  .p-datepicker-group
  .p-datepicker-calendar-container
  .p-datepicker-calendar
  tbody
  tr
  td {
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 3px !important;
}

.date-filter-panel {
  max-width: 260px !important;
  table td > span:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .p-datepicker-buttonbar {
    padding: 8px 8px;
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(100% - 19px);
    top: 48px;
    left: 9.5px;
    border: none;
    gap: 10px;
  }

  .p-monthpicker-month {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .p-yearpicker {
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
  .p-yearpicker-year {
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  .p-datepicker-header {
    border: none;
    padding-top: 0;
  }
  .calendar-button {
    color: #737986;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #d5d9eb;
    background-color: #f8f9fc;
    padding: 4px 16px;
    width: 124px;
    font-size: 13px;
    span {
      font-family: "Inter-Medium";
      font-weight: 500;
    }
  }
  .tommorow-button::before {
    content: "Tommorrow";
    font-family: "Inter-Medium";
  }
  .tommorow-button {
    span {
      display: none;
    }
  }
  .selected-button {
    border: 1px solid var(--color-primary);
    color: var(--color-primary);
  }
}

What I Have Tried:

I have implemented the handleMouseOver function to update the highlighted range.
I utilized getDatesBetween to calculate the dates to highlight.
I ensured that event listeners for mouseover are attached to the day cells.

Current Behavior
Currently, when I hover over dates after the first selected date, the expected range gets highlighted correctly, but causes flicker issue may be due to re-rendering.
Expected Behavior
I want when I hover any dates, dates in range should get highlighed without flicker and without causing any unnecessary re-rendering.
What might I be missing in my implementation that prevents the proper highlighting of dates across years? Any suggestions or insights on how to fix this behavior would be greatly appreciated!

I have developed a code that somewhat meets the function you want. If you want, you can review it here and apply the code. It will work when you change it as you wish and apply it. Here I showed how to highlight the values ​​in the range reached after the first date. You can add it to the Primereact Calendar range component and try it. It may not work exactly as you want, but you can fix it by updating the code.
         pt={{
            day: {
              onMouseOver: (e: any) => {
                const dayToHighlight: any = [];
                if (dates?.[0] && !dates?.[1]) {
                  if (
                    e.relatedTarget['innerText'] >= dates[0].getDay()
                  ) {
                    for (
                      let i = dates[0].getDay();
                      i <= e.relatedTarget['innerText'];
                      i++
                    )
                      dayToHighlight.push(i);
                  }
                  const elements = document.querySelectorAll(
                    '.p-datepicker-calendar tbody tr td span'
                  );
                  elements.forEach((element) =>
                    dayToHighlight.includes(+element.innerHTML)
                      ? (element.className = 'p-highlight')
                      : element.className = ''
                  );
                }
              },
            },
          }}

